# Converting Crystal to SSRS: How to use "if" in where clause?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am manually converting an existing Crystal Report to SSRS.  In the CR selection formula, part of the formula includes the following:

```
(if {?SubStatus}="O" then {SLHD.Status}<2 else
if {?SubStatus}="C" then {SLHD.Status}=2 else 1=1)
```

NOTE:  ?SubStatus is a parameter.

How do I code this in an SQL WHERE clause so that I can use it in SSRS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this is where the Crystal report will filter the data for `SLHD.Status < 2` when the SubStatus parameter is `O` but if the SubStatus Parameter is `C` then the SLHD.Status must be 2.

I think it would actually be easier to use a CASE statement in this case. The CASE is similar to an IF but with multiple possibilities without nesting IFs.

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @SubStatus NOT IN ('O', 'C') THEN 1
           WHEN @SubStatus = 'O' AND SLHD.Status < 2 THEN 1
           WHEN @SubStatus = 'C' AND SLHD.Status = 2 THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END = 1
```